# Generic user based width

Tags: html, css

I just started learning HTML today and was wondering how to have generic width so it fits the screen perfectly across every screen resolution?

Here is my current code, I tried using percents but code no worky!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>

<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="70%">
<a href="">
<img src="Resource/Header.png">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that using tables for layout is generally looked down upon these days.

Comment: @icktoofay use `<div>` instead?

Comment: If you want a quick solution, try [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). If you are trying to learn, research responsive design.

Comment: @Joe: `div` can be used as a container element if necessary. Sometimes if your document is already heavily structured no new elements need to be added.

Comment: As @GeorgeCummins said, this is one of the best solutions for fluid layouts but it might be a little bit advanced, if it's your first day, I would go with some basic markups without caring to much about fluid layouts, and the start looking up on the bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your table to span the full width of the screen you should define it like this:

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
...
```

In general don't use the `width` attribute but rather the `style` attribute

Also noted in the comments, it's better to use semantic markup and put your CSS in external files, but if your just starting out, it's probably a good way to get going.

Some other links you might find useful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Tutorials

http://getbootstrap.com/ => Advanced CSS framework (I would advice you to learn the basics first)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do. One interpretation is that you're trying to have an image left-aligned inside a box which occupies 70% of the page's width (here showing `Resource/Header.png` to be 300 pixels wide):

[image]

In that case, you need to add two empty columns and fix the table's width to 100% of the page:

```html
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="15%"></td>
        <td width="70%"><img src="Resource/Header.png"></td>
        <td width="15%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

<sup><kbd>[**Try it**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3c8E/)</kbd> on JSFiddle.</sup>

It's also a possibility that you want the image to take the whole 100% of the cell—that is, 70% of the page. In that case, you need to fix the width of the image to 100%:

```html
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="15%"></td>
        <td width="70%"><img src="Resource/Header.png" width="100%"></td>
        <td width="15%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

<sup><kbd>[**Try it**](http://jsfiddle.net/q7gA9/)</kbd> on JSFiddle.</sup>

---

## …but tables are for tabular data, not for layout.

Fortunately, every result we've achieved up to now is trivial to achieve using CSS. We need a container and an image:

```html
<header>  <!-- header is a new tag in HTML 5; use something else if you want -->
    <img src="Resources/Header.png">
</header>
```

Then, you need to style it up with some CSS:

```css
header {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

<sup><kbd>[**Try it**](http://jsfiddle.net/4R5rB/)</kbd> on JSFiddle.</sup>

I think the `margin: 0 auto;` line requires some explanation. We are using shorthand style, where we first provide the vertical margins and then the horizontal margins. It is equivalent to

```css
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
```

We don't actually care about the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`; what actually makes it do anything is the `margin-left` and `margin-right`. When one of the margins is `auto`, the browser will use that margin to fill up any extra space. When both are auto, it will evenly distribute the space between them, thus evenly padding out both sides and centering our element.

Now say we want the latter style we achieved with the table. Then we give the `img` all of the space within that element:

```css
header > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

<sup><kbd>[**Try it**](http://jsfiddle.net/GWXSD/)</kbd> on JSFiddle.</sup>

Note that we only needed to change the CSS, and none of the HTML needed to change. This is one advantage of using CSS over tables for layout—change the styles in one place, everything that uses those styles is updated. Also note that the code using CSS is shorter, although this isn't always the case.

---

## …but we still aren't accessible.

If you have an image, *always* add an `alt` attribute. The `alt` attribute is supposed to be a replacement for the image if the user agent cannot display the image, or if the user is blind, etc. For your header, whatever text appears would be fine:

```html
<img src="Resources/Header.png" alt="Frank's Flower Shop">
```

For purely decorative elements, `alt=""` should be used. (Yes, an empty `alt` is better than no `alt`—but only when it is purely decorative.) Refrain from describing what it is—instead, provide content that could adequately replace the image. (e.g., “screenshot” is bad; “the main window contains a toolbar and a content viewing area” is much better.)

But if it's a header, a search engine might put less weight on the `alt` text of an image than if it were right there. It turns out that there's a trick we can do with CSS to achieve this. First, write out the HTML as it would appear to a search engine or user with a screenreader:

```html
<header>
    <h1><a href="http://www.example.com/">Frank's Flowers</a></h1>
</header>
```

Then we can put the image as a background on the `h1` and dedent the text out of view:

```css
h1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(Resources/Header.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -10000px;
}
```

Ta-da! Unfortunately, it's harder to combine this approach with scaling the image. In newer browsers, you can use `background-size`, but that was only introduced in CSS 3. For greatest compatibility, you may want to consider using plain text where possible and aligning that over a decorative background or just not scaling it.

Comment: As a last note, I'd recommend not jumping to Bootstrap (or any other CSS framework, for that matter, possibly excepting reset stylesheets) unless you know it's exactly what you need. It's a big dependency, and you can often achieve similar effects with strategically placed bits of code you write yourself. While figuring out what that bit is might not be easy when you're a beginner, figuring it out makes you a more effective CSS-writer.